# Why RecyclerView is scrolling way too more above the first item and flickering while scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayout

**EDIT**: The problem is solved !!

My `RecyclerView` flickers while scrolling. There are 5-6 items in single screen.
When I scroll down, the screen flickers and the scroller jumps back to the top of the `RecyclerView`. Now after that if I scroll up again, the `ReccyclerView` scrolls way too more above the first item. If I repeated the scrolling up and down process very fast, the recycler view completely scrolls down leaving just a empty background. And after that if I scroll either ways nothing shows up. Scroller does not work again after this.

I am using `Lucasr Two Way View`.
The problem I am discussing is also mentioned in [Some weird with recyclerView.Adapter and UIL](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/issues/159) but not solved yet. I have more than 20 images in my `RecyclerView`, which could be increased. Each image is of size greater than 100kb.

For loading image, I tried `Universal Image Loader(UIL)` with caching enabled. But it didn't help.The flickering persists with `UIL`.
I also tested with `GLIDE` but problem is still there.

To make it more clearer here is the snapshots from my `ADM`.
[image: <code>RecyclerView</code> Flickering During Scrolling Issue.]

Here's my Holder Class:

```
public class TileAdapter extends BaseTwoWayViewAdapter {

private static final String TAG = makeLogTag(TileAdapter.class);
private Context context;
private List<UserCategory> itemsList;

public TileAdapter(Context context, List<Tile> itemsList) {
    super(context, itemsList);
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}

@Override
public TestHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_tile_full_length, null);
    TestHolder tileHolder = new TestHolder(v);
    return tileHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Test tile = itemsList.get(position);
    final TestHolder tileHolder = (TestHolder) holder;
    final View itemView = tileHolder.itemView;
    tileHolder.bindHolder(tile);
}

/**
 * View Holder class
 */
public class TestHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView titleTextView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public TestHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    void bindHolder(final Tile tile) {
        titleTextView.setText(tile.getName());

        if(imageView != null) {                
            ViewParent parent = imageView.getParent();
            int backgroundColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor);
            if (parent != null && parent instanceof View) {
                ((View) parent).setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
            } else {
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
            }

            imageLoader.loadImageUsingResId(tile.getImageResourcesId(), true, imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

}

And Here's how I am setting up the adapter to RecyclerView:

```
TileAdapter tileAdapter = new TileAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(tileAdapter);
```

Comment: Instead of "EDIT: The problem is solved !!" you can just accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by replacing BaseLayoutManager file of Lucasr Two Way View file as given [here](https://github.com/0legg/twoway-view/commit/a59232e6a31aa89ca9dfd26ec0457e32193a1c64!)